# Mostrar os votos negativos e votos positivos, descrevendo melhor a realidade para os usuários

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Queria deixar como sugestão a mudança da pontuação do meta, descrevendo os votos positivos e votos negativos, já visto que no final um **-1** não reflete por exemplo **9** votos positivos e **10** votos negativos como a vontade real da comunidade, mas, nesse caso exemplo reflete um empate técnico entre os fatores que apoiam e que discordam.

***Exemplo:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem só é uma ilustração grotesca, mas dá a ideia real que foram *9 - 10* que resultou ***-1***. Assim dando a amplitude necessária para mostrar que houve um empate técnico e não apenas houve um voto ***-1***.

Comment: Eu apoio! Normalmente, quem possui um certo número de pontos de reputação ([750 atualmente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) já pode ver essa contagem, os demais usuários não. Não sei o porquê dessa regra, mas de todo modo eu concordo que pelo menos no meta deveria ser diferente: pelos motivos já apresentados na pergunta.

Comment: Qual é a pontuação @mgibsonbr, que um usuário novo tem que ter para fazer debate no meta (adicionar questão, comentários e resposta)?

Comment: [Apenas 5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). Tirando os recém-chegados - que nunca fizeram nada ainda - todo mundo pode participar do meta. Você pode ver [a lista completa de privilégios aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Obrigada @mgibsonbr

Comment: Eu também apoio. Isso me incomodou durante muito tempo no metão, até eu ter reputação suficiente para ver a contagem de votos. [Cheguei a tratar disso numa resposta minha lá](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142561/167534), sobre um assunto relacionado.

Comment: Suspeito que isso é uma questão de otimização do banco de dados. [Essa resposta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) mostra que por ser uma operação custosa tal recurso é limitado apenas para alguns usuários.

Comment: Então, @Kyllopardiun, mas, pense para fazer a operação 9 - 10 ele tem que pegar em uma operação custoso do mesmo jeito. Eu discordo.

Comment: Faz sentido. Mas a proposta seria de remover completamente o limite, ou diminuir para algum valor específico?

Comment: @Maria, não a reposta explica o porque a operação é custosa, veja-a e entenderá o por quê. (não estou defendendo a posição do SE só estou explicando o porque dessa decisão de design).

Comment: @Gabe na seta de cima vai aparecer o número de votos que apoiam e na seta de baixo os votos que discordam só isso, mostrar a realidade.

Comment: Então @Kyllopardiun eu discordo, porque, o custoso fica na mesma!

Comment: @Maria Então removendo o limite atual de reputação para poder ver essa informação, certo?

Comment: E o custo não é o mesmo. A pontuação mostrada no post (-1) é armazenada **diretamente** no banco de dados, por questões de desempenho. E atualizada quando há algum voto. Não é feita nenhuma conta na hora de *mostrar* os dados.

Comment: Poderia remover, ou poderia deixar, podemos ter várias ideias para melhorar essa informação.

Comment: Entendi @Gabe, se colocar mais um campo com votos sendo guardados então os positivos no que já existe e os negativos no outro criado acredito que a operação de busca não terá tanta degradação.

Comment: Apesar que é uma mudança drástica, porque, as outras respostas não tem como saber o que foi votado @Gabe, até concordo nesse ponto, agora de desempenho nem tanto.

Comment: @Maria É uma possibiliade, mas que teria que ser feita para **todos** os posts do Stack Exchange (diversos milhões de registros). Eu posso certamente levar isso aos devs, mas a gente precisa apresentar uma proposta **formal**, que solucione todos os problemas das propostas anteriores, e que justifique o trabalho de desenvolimento. Se conseguirmos fazer isso, a SE é toda ouvidos.

Comment: Bom @Gabe como funciona esse documento porque posso propor. tem sim vários pontos mas, eu acredito que essa visão melhora demais

Comment: @Maria Eu concordo que melhora. O ideal seria alguém, em uma resposta aqui, justificar (até mesmo tecnicamente, com base na [justificativa do Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) porque isso deve ser feito. Transformar o banco de dados, e alterar milhões de registros dessa maneira vai exigir muito trabalho e precisamos ter um bom motivo.

Comment: @Maria Eu também concordo que não é tão complicado colocar mais duas colunas numa tabela e popular essas colunas (assim a tabela de posts passaria a ter *score*, *upvotes* e *downvotes*). Mas considerando que a implementação atual (que exige um clique para ver up/down separadamente) já resolve em parte o problema de performance, acho que bastaria reduzir a reputação necessária para poder ver essa contagem no clique.

Comment: @bfavaretto O problema de reduzir o requisito de reputação é justamente ter mais pessoas clicando nessa informação, o que leva a mais requests, e mais `SELECTs` e mais carga nos servidores. Se o requisito baixar, tem que estar atrelado a uma medida técnica que compense a carga extra.

Comment: @Gabe 1 - O motivo que você deseja, chama-se mudar, inovar, querer um algo melhor, melhorar a informação, do jeito que está não reflete a verdade, é um dado não é uma informação. 2 - O que é mais engraçado nisso tudo é que o `request` vai continuar o mesmo, sendo que a informação gerada vai possui mais um campo que tem a função de guardar os dowvoter, porque o upvoter a tabela já contém. Tecnicamente vai ser um Json com mais uma informação e o select de 1 campo vai ser 2, não tem essa complexidade toda, o pior vai ser na hora de transformar o sistema atual para esse novo.

Comment: Porque a idéia é o seguinte os votos que estiverem menor que `0` vão para o campo downvoter, e o campo upvoter recebe 0, e claro o layout um pequeno ajuste de css, por isso não vejo complexidade nem desempenho ruim @Gabe

Comment: @Maria A coluna que tem hoje na tabela não é de upvotes, e sim score (número de upvotes - número de downvotes).

Comment: Sim, Ok, @bfavaretto

Comment: @bfavaretto não existe mais problema de performance hoje em dia. O limite mínimo de reputação para ver scores é apenas by design mesmo.

Comment: @Renan O problema de performance foi mitigado com a solução de mostrar os votos separadamente somente quando solicitado. Se fosse para mostrar toda vez, seria oneroso buscar isso no banco, pois a informação está normalizada.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu estava enganado em meu comentário anterior. Para reforçar o seu comentário, encontrei este do Servy no meta original (primeiro comentário na pergunta): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255675/view-vote-counts-instead-of-score-as-default-for-established-users

Comment: @Renan Ou seja, o argumento deles é que pra atualizar o total de votos basta 1 update, enquanto pra atualizar positivos e negativos precisaria de 2? Isso é ridículo! Quando alguém vota a favor, você só precisa atualizar os mais. Quando alguém vota contra, só os menos... Continua um único update por voto.

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu até entendo o quanto isso é ridículo, mas o modelo atual realmente é o mais rápido possível para se mostrar apenas o total de votos. Vale lembrar que o volume de acessos de toda a rede é considerável, então realmente há economia dessa forma.

Comment: @Renan eu não discordo que a desnormalização seja uma coisa boa, o que eu afirmo é que uma alternativa poderia tanto permitir o acesso irrestrito aos dois totais quanto **melhorar** a performance [global] em vez de piorar (salvo por uma micro-desotimização que não deve ser relevante, mesmo na escala do SE - se não me engano). Veja [esse meu outro comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1855/mostrar-os-votos-negativos-e-votos-positivos-descrevendo-melhor-a-realidade-par#comment5518_1858) para uma explicação.

Comment: @mgibsonbr O problema não é tanto a desotimização de **escrita**, mas sim a de **leitura**. Uma query extra pra cada page view nosso é uma porrada enorme no servidor (por isso o score do post é desnormalizado). Reduzir o requisito tornaria possível que mais pessoas pudessem fazer um request que já é custoso (por envolver `JOIN`), e temos sempre que ter atenção com isso.

Comment: Maria, a interface para mostrar `+` e `-` **já existe**, é uma questão de privilégio poder vê-la no sistema, talvez pudesse esclarer isso na sua pergunta? . . .  Mas quem não tem privilégio pode usar a API como mostro na minha resposta, o que me traz à pergunta: já testou o User Script? :) Acho que por agora a extensão do Chrome não vai ser útil aqui no SOpt, fiz uma feature-request lá no StackApps pro autor incluir o pt.so

Comment: @Gabe Claro, mas é que eu vi múltiplos argumentos contra essa proposta. Estava rebatendo um deles. O outro é igualmente trivial - em vez de desnormalizar uma coluna, fazê-lo em duas. De modo que em vez de ter `Id,Titulo,Score` passaria a ter `Id,Titulo,Up,Down`. E em tempo, não estou afirmando que é uma mudança que se deva fazer levianamente, somente que é factível (as reais implicações, só os devs podem dizer). P.S. Vi seu update técnico, e está tudo consistente com o meu entendimento anterior - e minha sugestão de mudança.

Comment: @brasofilo, existe uma confusão, eu não to dizendo desse recurso esquece esse recurso, eu estou dizendo mostrar o valor de cara, tanto negativos e positivos e dar a realidade melhor de votos. Na parte técnica existem maneiras de ter aproximadamente a mesma velocidade do atual, é um fator que só os programadores em testes poderiam demonstrar bom é isso.

Answer (score 7):

Complementando um pouco a resposta do OnoSendai, que busca argumentos para justificar ou refutar a implementação desse recurso:

- Nos meta-sites, o acesso à contagem dos votos é mais relevante, especialmente nos pedidos de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso). Se for para fazer alguma mudança, eu começaria com os metas.
- Para além do debate técnico sobre o peso disso e a dificuldade (ou não) de implementação, eu sou absolutamente contra mostrar as contagens separadamente *o tempo todo*. E é por um motivo bem simples: a maioria das postagens não é polêmica, e essa informação seria simplesmente redundante.
- Devido ao ponto anterior, eu acho suficiente o recurso como está hoje: a contagem é mostrada quando clicamos no saldo.
- E devido a tudo isso: sou a favor que a reputação necessária para ver a contagem no meta seja reduzida, quem sabe até para 1 voto. Mas não votei a favor deste pedido de novo recurso pois ele é sobre mostrar a contagem o tempo todo.

Comment: "a maioria das postagens não é polêmica". Exatamente. :)

Comment: De fato, não há benefício real para a comunidade. Seria algo só para agradar algum usuário que ainda não tem pontos suficientes para ver a votação separada e está desesperado para ver esse resultado.

Comment: @bigown desculpa mas, não tem nada a ver o que você disse !!! não tem desespero de ninguém, é um questionamento e acredito mais na informação real do que em um número que não significa nada!

Comment: Eu concordo com o argumento de irrelevância da informação para a maioria dos casos. Além disso, alguns casos de viés em votações (votos que seguem o movimento inicial, votos por pena, etc) não seriam necessariamente resolvidos. Continuo achando que baixar o requisito de reputação seja a solução que faça mais sentido.

Answer (score 6):

Eu não acredito que esta funcionalidade seja tão necessária a ponto de demandar uma modificação do mecanismo atual.

Na minha opinião, os usuários do SO podem se dividir em 4 categorias:

- O usuário não registrado que chega até o SO via Google ou similares;
- usuário *light* que até tem uma conta, mas não interage muito;
- O usuário *not-so-light* que participa ativamente (acredito que eu me encaixe nessa categoria);
- Heavy Users (estou olhando pra você, @bfavaretto.)

Assim, eu tenho 3 perguntas a fazer:

- Quais dessas categorias iriam se beneficiar e se interessar em saber a divisão entre votos positivos e negativos?
- Dentre essas categorias, qual é a distribuição percentual em relação à totalidade de usuários do site?
- A exibição da divisão é, do ponto de vista de usabilidade, algo positivo ou negativo para a totalidade dos usuários?

Se me fizessem essas três perguntas, minhas respostas seriam: Apenas **Heavy Users**, **1%** e **negativo**.

Heavy Users já tem acesso a esta informação de qualquer maneira.

Quanto à usabilidade, deixo com vocês essa imagem.
Dica: Para design de aplicativos web, na maioria das vezes *menos* é *mais*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente, concordo com tudo. Exceto com ser chamado de *heavy user*. Eu não peso nem 80 quilos! :)

Comment: Eu ia discordar da sua primeira pergunta, mas normalmente se um post (pergunta ou resposta) está muito polarizado (+9 vs -10) isso é refletido na linha de comentários, ou seja, o visitante casual e atento vai ter *feedback* que tem algo "estranho" acontecendo ali.

Comment: Creio que seria interessante ter o limite de 125 pontos de reputação (a mesma quantidade que permite o voto negativo) para o uso desse recurso. Não sou heavy user e gostaria de ter acesso à essa ferramenta.

Answer (score 5):

Ao atingir 750 pontos de reputação, você será capaz de ver as contagens. Basta clicar na pontuação de qualquer post as quantidades de votos positivos e negativos serão mostradas.

Apenas continue participando e você terá esse [privilégio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

Comment: A questão @Renan é que esse dado se torne informação, e não por reputação, para demonstrar a realidade de votos que concordam e votos que não concordam. Ficar clicando também tem um fator de acessibilidade e informação. O questionamento é mais amplo!

Comment: @Maria Então acho melhor editar o título e a pergunta para deixar claro que você propõe os votos positivos e negativos sempre visíveis, sem necessidade de clique. Se colocar também uma imagem ilustrando sua ideia, melhor ainda.

Comment: @bfavaretto foi editada pelo Gabe, eu vou reeditar ...

Comment: @bfavaretto editada a questão, se por acaso achar outra interpretação melhor do texto, editar por favor.

Comment: Ok @Maria. Retirei meu upvote porque não gosto dessa ideia de mostrar sempre (mas concordaria em reduzir ou eliminar os requisitos de reputação para ver o placar no clique).

Comment: @bfavaretto esse menos um (-1) não reflete a realidade, é isso que quero demonstrar ... porque essa questão já teve 3 votos positivos ou 2 agora. Então o -1 fica vago, mas, tudo bem é bom como exemplo.

Comment: @Renan acho que é exatamente isto. O custo não compensa o benefício, se é que tem algum, pode até ser malefício para algumas pessoas. Ver os votos separadamente beneficia quem é usuário bem ativo e quem tem menos de centenas de pontos ainda não pode ser considerado muito ativo.

Comment: @bigown eu acredito que você não entendeu nada, como muita gente não entendeu. Custo, nem vai ter, só benefícios agora os usuários que estão começando passam por coisa pior, bem pior!

Comment: @Maria o custo do qual falamos está nas consultas que o sistema vai fazer ao banco de dados. Esse custo é bem real.

Comment: @Renan você está preocupado com DBA e isso não é para você é para os desenvolvedores resolver, entenda a questão é informação.

Comment: `"e isso não é para você é para os desenvolvedores resolver"` você quer uma mudança e nós estamos indicando o motivo de porque ela não será feita. Se você for propor a mesma coisa aos desenvolvedores (em http://meta.stackexchange.com), você vai ter a mesma resposta. Isso já foi pedido ao menos dez vezes antes.

Comment: @Renan, temos que mudar! esse gênero pessimista!

Answer (score 5):

Bastante tempo atrás alguém [pediu algo **parecido**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/175506) no SOen e o Jeff deu a seguinte justificativa:

> A pontuação de um post é [desnormalizada](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desnormaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o), mas o número de votos (para cima ou para baixo) não é.
>   Então exibir o número de votos em todos os posts implicaria em fazer mais 2 queries no banco de dados, vezes o número de perguntas/respostas visíveis. Nosso banco de dados é bem rápido, mas a tabela de votos é gigantesca e *não fazer* uma query é sempre mais rápido que *fazer uma query*.
>
> É algo que poderíamos implementar "on-demand", mas é impensável fazer de forma a sempre ser mostrado.

Essa resposta deu origem à implementação que temos hoje, onde pode-se clicar na pontuação para ver a distribuição dos votos desde que se tenha reputação suficiente. Reduzir esse limite, mesmo que apenas nos Metas, implicaria em mais requisições ao banco de dados e menos desempenho.

Não discordo de maneira alguma que isso seria algo bom de se ter mas não pode ocorrer às custas de desempenho nos sites. Se isso for implementado, valeria para todos os metas da SE e acarretaria em centenas, ou provavelmente milhares, de queries por segundo.

## UPDATE TÉCNICO

Tá rolando bastante discussão sobre a parte de otimização ou não dessa questão de votos, então vou explicar melhor como está o nosso banco de dados.

Nossa tabela de `Posts` contém um campo desnormalizado `Posts.Score`, que contem a pontuação daquele post (seja uma pergunta ou uma resposta) no momento. Dessa maneira:

```
 Id | Titulo | Score
----|--------|-------
 01 | foo    |  02
```

Nós também temos uma tabela `Votes`, que contém todos os votos, e está relacionada à tabela `Posts`, desse jeito:

```
 Id | PostId | UserId | VoteType
----|--------|--------|----------
 01 | 01     | 01     | up
 02 | 01     | 02     | down
 03 | 01     | 03     | up
 04 | 01     | 04     | up
```

O campo `Posts.Score` é desnormalizado porque é informação *redundante*, já que podemos conseguir o score de um post facilmente, com uma query na tabela de votos. Informações redundantes são ruins para a escrita, mas facilitam muito a leitura. A normalização/desnormalização da sua tabela é algo que você tem que adotar com base nas necessidades do **seu** sistema.

O Stack Exchange lida com **muitos** votos por dia. O processo de escrita é impactado por conta destas informações redundantes, mas o nosso volume de **leituras** no banco é absurdamente maior. Em termos de desempenho, um `UPDATE` a mais cada vez que alguém vota não representa a mesma carga que uma query extra, ou uma subquery, ou um `JOIN` teria cada vez que uma página é acessada. Não gostamos de `JOIN`s.

Quando você acessa uma pergunta, o `Posts.score` é retornado direto. Sem nenhuma outra operação de leitura. Isso é rápido. E todo mundo fica feliz. Quando você clica no score, temos que ir fazer mais uma operação de leitura no banco, na tabela `Votes`. Isso é rápido se fizermos isso apenas nas eventuais vezes em que usuários acima do limite desejam ver a distribuição dos votos mas se diminuirmos o limite, *quantas dessas requisições passariam a ser feitas por segundo*?

Se formos fazer essa atualização, e diminuir esse limite, precisamos de um ótimo motivo. Esse pedido já foi feito diversas vezes ao longo dos anos, mas nunca foi atendido. Precisa haver uma justificativa forte por trás, se formos criar algo assim.

Comment: se a gente ficar pensando dessa forma, nunca chegaremos a lugar nenhum, eu acredito que fazer o documento igual você relatou e mandar para eles analisarem seria um proposta melhor, do que ficar discutimos desempenho sem ao menos passar a proposta para eles, porque, se fosse assim o `facebook` não funcionaria, imagine só esse exemplo.

Comment: Eu tenho quase absoluta certeza de que a questão do desempenho não é mais relevante. Vou rever as discussões lá no metão.

Comment: Acabo de ver um comentário do Servy em uma pergunta relativamente recente sobre o assunto. Realmente, o motivo para não se mostrar contagens de votos para todos ainda é performance (primeiro comentário em http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255675/view-vote-counts-instead-of-score-as-default-for-established-users)

Comment: Hoje temos uma coluna desnormalizada (vou chamar de "totais"), que precisa ser atualizada toda vez que alguém clica em ambas as setas (pra cima e pra baixo, seja "vote" ou "unvote"). Caso tívessmos duas ("positivos" e "negativos") continuaríamos tendo que fazer um único update cada vez que alguém clica numa seta (uma operação distinta pras setas pra cima e pra baixo). Ao fazer um select, bastaria buscar as três coisas: "positivos", "negativos" e "positivos" - "negativos" as "total". Colocando em um hidden input, e mostrando via JavaScript. A performance ia **melhorar** em relação à de hoje.

Comment: @mgibsonbr discordo que a performance melhoraria. O tempo de fetch dos votos seria o dobro do que é hoje na carga da página, pois é uma coluna a mais para retornar.

Comment: @Renan Essa é a "micro-desotimização" de que falei. Dificilmente acarretaria no dobro do tempo - só se a coluna "totais" fosse a única a ser buscada... (única mesmo: id, nome do post, etc, tudo isso amortiza o custo de cada coluna individual). Do mesmo modo, o acréscimo no payload (o HTML gerado) também seria desprezível. O ganho de performance **global** a que me refiro é que essa requisição adicional para obter as contagens - uma requisição HTTP completa, com hit no banco - deixaria de ser necessária em absoluto. Essa é minha visão, mas com certeza posso estar enganado...

Comment: "mas se diminuirmos o limite, quantas dessas requisições passariam a ser feitas por segundo?" Aí é que está! Se fossem duas colunas desnormlizadas em vez de uma, essas requisições extra cairiam pra **zero** - não seria necessário nenhuma requisição adicional para obter essas contagens.

Comment: @mgibsonbr De acordo. Mas desnormalizar as duas colunas passa também por fazer um `UPDATE` em todos os nosso registros até hoje. Não é uma decisão que a gente pode tomar sem ponderar antes. E até agora tá todo mundo se perdendo nas possibilidades técnicas de se fazer isso, mas ninguém se ateve a discutir os benefícios/malefícios à comunidade que essa alteração pode trazer. Porque queremos ver os votos? Que decisão isso nos ajuda a tomar?

Comment: @Gabe Eu concordo! E os impactos não param aí - uma mudança na estrutura do banco afetaria a API de dados por exemplo... De novo, não é trivial, só factível. E acho que o pessoal agarrou na discussão da parte técnica porque somos desenvolvedores, é nisso que mais pensamos hehe! Também porque é difícil falar em benefícios/malefícios quando a posição oficial é que "não vai mudar e pronto". Mostrando que a mudança é factível, pode-se debater mais tranquilamente se ela é desejável ou não.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Hum... Pelo visto passei a impressão errada. Erro meu. A questão não é "não vamos mudar e pronto", mas sim "isso já foi rejeitado antes. Que argumento vocês tem para nos convencer do contrário?". Onde você achar que eu poderia esclarecer isso melhor?

Comment: @Gabe Não, não foi você que passou essa impressão. Foram as discussões no MSE, [esse comentário por exemplo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255675/view-vote-counts-instead-of-score-as-default-for-established-users#comment26201_255675). Esse é um comentário relativamente recente (vi também [essa discussão](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/747/177950), e outras semelhantes, mas elas são mais antigas e não devem estar atualizadas com a situação atual).

Comment: @mgibsonbr O comentário de "optimized for that from the start" é verdadeiro, acredito eu. O Shog tem vários motivos pelos quais permitir acesso à distribuição dos votos não seja uma boa ideia. E não vi ninguém atacar **esse** problema ainda. Tá todo mundo discutindo DBA hahaha

Comment: @Gabe É, eu não vi os argumentos do Shog. O que eu vi foi muita gente defendendo o acesso às contagens positivas/negativas, argumentando que um post +3 parece bom, mas um +28/-25 demonstra claramente que ele é um post polêmico. O que é bem a motivação por trás da OP ter aberto esse pedido aqui - permitir que os usuários vejam, no meta, as posições que são consenso e aquelas que não são (particularmente relevante no caso da pergunta do on-topic, na minha opinião).

Comment: Eu concordo com o @Gabe que a discussão deveria ser primariamente em relação ao real benefício da mudança. É verdade que uma postagem com +28/-25 é claramente um conteúdo polêmico. Mas, convenhamos, essa polêmica está também bem clara na discussão que necessariamente acompanha esse tipo de conteúdo. O +3 resultante é apenas uma indicação "média" (digamos) da visão da comunidade. Além do mais, conteúdos polêmicos me parecem ser minoria. Qual seria a real utilidade para os leitores de se mostrar +4/-1 se a grande maioria das postagens não é, de fato, polêmica?

Comment: Se a questão fosse só de DBA, bastaria ter mais **duas** colunas, up e down, **mantendo** o score pra preservar a API atual, pois mesmo nos volumes da SE, não seriam tão traumaticos assim **se houvesse algum benefício mínimo** em troca. O que eu não consigo imaginar é o benefício que isso vai trazer pro usuário final.

Comment: Acreditem, (-10, +9) é diferente de (-1, +0), isso pode mudar muita coisa. Tentem ver do ponto de vista do usuário, uma resposta (-1, +0) é muito mais tendenciosa à receber votos negativos do que uma resposta (-10, +9).

Comment: @Patrick Não deveria. As pessoas deviam votar com base em sua própria opinião sobre a resposta, sem se influenciarem pelo placar.

Comment: @bfavaretto as pessoas votam assim, por influência sim isso é fato! Quando eles tem um -3 eles colocam um -4 isso é fato em todo SO!

Comment: @Patrick Pode ser. Mas uma resposta (-10, +9) também apresenta uma tendência maior de receber votos **positivos**, com o raciocídio de "equilibrar", entende?

Answer (score 5):

Como é frequente em muitos pedidos de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso), é possível alcançar a mudança desejada usando algum User Script. E no Stack Apps existe um que usa a API para consultar a quantidade de votos de qualquer post:

> ## [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)
>
> <sub>*750 no caso do SOpt, que ainda está em fase beta*</sub>
>
> [image]

---

### Para incluir o SOPT nesse User Script

Adicione um asterisco na primeira URL, `*.stackoverflow.com` em vez de `stackoverflow.com`:

```
// @match          http://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
```

e com isso pode-se remover a linha seguinte:

```
// @match          http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
```

Sugiro deletar os sites onde já se tem esse privilégio. E também usar o `exclude` para remover sites específicos que caem dentro de `*.stackexchange.com`, p.ex.:

```
// @exclude        http://meta.stackexchange.com/*
```